# checkbox reactjs is checking all options

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, use-state

I'm using a material-ui checkbox that uses state.
When I click to select an option, it selects all, but I would like him to select only the one that was clicked.

[image]

code:

```
export default function Categorys() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    checkedG: true
  });

  const handleChange = event => {
    setState({ ...state, [event.target.name]: event.target.checked });
  };
  return (
    <>
      {categorys.map(category => (
        <FormControlLabel
          key={category.id}
          control={
            <GreenCheckbox
              checked={state.checkedG}
              onChange={handleChange}
              name="checkedG"
              key={category.id}
            />
          }
          label={category.name}
        />
      ))}
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because they all have the same checked attribute.
Change it to:

```
export default function Categorys() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({});

  const handleChange = event => {
    setState(prevState => { ...prevState, [event.target.name]: event.target.checked });
  };
  return (
    <>
      {categorys.map(category => (
        <FormControlLabel
          key={category.id}
          control={
            <GreenCheckbox
              checked={state[category.id]}
              onChange={handleChange}
              name={category.id}
              key={category.id}
            />
          }
          label={category.name}
        />
      ))}
    </>
  );
}
```